# React native images with dash in name fail to load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

in my react-native project, my images are named and linked like

```
../assets/img/image-item-left.jpg
```

the import fails because of the dash in the name of the image. 
Error: Unexpected character

But when I change the name and path of the image from dash to underscore like

```
../assets/img/image_item_left.jpg
```

the import works.

Changing every name to an underscore-name doesn't work for me, because I haven't the control over the asset-production and its  image-naming.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.
Lance.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Found the solution.
You don't need to point at the file by a path, just include it like this.
<Image source={{uri: 'imagename'}}/> does the trick.